# Long listing a Directory

Tags: command-line, directory, ls

2 Questions:

1) How should I long list a directory. Kindly guide me if there's are multiple options to do this .?
2) How do I sort based on the file size?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Have you read the manual pages (`man ls`)?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use `| more` and scroll with space or down arrow. like this:
`/# ls /etc/ | more`

2) For sorting by file size use `ls -lS`  or `ls -lSh` for print sizes in KB MB or GB.
If you wanna invert the result, use -r switch. `ls -lShr`
For more arguments `ls --help`